# Cloud9 on Raspberry Pi 2 debug with sudo

Tags: node.js, cloud9-ide, raspberry-pi2

I installed Cloud9 on Raspberry Pi 2 and now I am trying to create Node.js classic "Hello world" app which will be blinking the LED connected to GPIO. I found this library to work with GPIO https://github.com/jperkin/node-rpio which is working great. But the script must be executed with sudo to be able to work with pins. So in Cloud9 I must use the bash panel and write "sudo node ./script.js". Is there some way how to create/modify runner to use sudo command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to create custom runner with this json:

```
{
  "cmd": [
    "bash",
    "-c",
    "sudo node ${debug?--nocrankshaft} ${debug?--nolazy} ${debug?--debug-brk=15454} $file $args"
  ],
  "debugger": "v8",
  "debugport": 15454,
  "selector": "source.js",
}
```

Node that it not contains the line from the original runner which was for node v0.x because I am using newer.

```
"${debug?`node --version | grep -vqE \"v0\\..\\.\" && echo --nodead_code_elimination`}",
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a nodejs runner in your workspace? Open up your script.js file then right click on the run button up the top to see all runners available.

If you do have this runner you can edit it by first clicking on it, then in the new runner window that appears click on the `Runner: Node.js (default)` in the top right of the window and then select "Edit runner". From there you can write `sudo` just before the word `node` on line 8 and then whenever you use that runner it will run in sudo mode.

Comment: That was not working but you showed me the correct way to the solution. Thank you.